# How to interpret React profiler flame chart?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

As per the React flame chart, the NaiveSameValuesEveryRender > ArrayComponent took almost twice as long to render as the MemoizedValues > ArrayComponent. The reason is because the bar is almost twice as wide.

[image: react profile results]

However, the tooltips say that the render times are identical. So what are the render times?

Render time for NaiveSameValuesEveryRender > ArrayComponent:

[image: Render time for NaiveSameValuesEveryRender]

Render time for MemoizedValues > ArrayComponent:

[image: Render time for MemoizedValues]